# Get value from Gridview into the another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2012

I have a gridview in one page as below.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDoctorList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" />
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPID" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("PatientId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientId" HeaderText="PatientId" SortExpression="PatientId" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="firstname" SortExpression="firstname" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastname" HeaderText="lastname" SortExpression="lastname" />

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="sex" HeaderText="sex" SortExpression="sex" />

                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [PatientId],[firstname], [lastname], [sex] FROM [PatientDetails]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now when user check on checkbox same time i want the PatientId from gridview into the another page and further I want to insert the PatientId into sql table.

Thank a lot if some one give me the code

**UPDATED :: **

My page_load code is

```
if (!IsPostBack) { 
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDoctorList.Rows)
 { 
   CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk"); 
   if (chk.Checked) 
    { 
     string patientId = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblPID")).Text; 
     string exam = ((Button)sender).Text; 
     Session[patientId] = patientId;
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Put put that parent id in a session variable and use it on the next page/ alternatively you can pass it as a query string while going to another page :)

Comment: where to put session at pageload?

Comment: you can use use session any where as per your use

Comment: can you check below i have put the code in pageload is correct?#

Comment: now what to do if i want these value in the another page?

Comment: -_- did you read my answer?? Session needs to have a "" mark inside like this `Session ["PatientID"]` you need to read more about ASP. because you'll never understand a problem without having the time to understand how to code.

Comment: read about sessions and how they work we are not teachers.

Comment: I have read about session...there is the value inside the session because i have put the if session is not null then only it should go inside the condition.....but when it goes inside the if condition...i can only see the value of session with "".....so i don't understand what value is inside.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try this??

```
Session ["PatientID"] = YoureGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[indexOfPatientID].Text;
```

by this the value of PatientID is in session when going to other Page you can retrieve the Data in the session using

```
Int PatientID = Convert.Toint16(Session["PatientID"]);
```

OR if its a string

```
   string PatientID = Session["PatientID"].ToString();
```

Well im guessing because you didnt provide enough information but that's how i code if im going to transfer a data to another web page

for inserting in SQL and assuming its TSQL i use something like this

```
        SqlCommand Update = new SqlCommand();
        Update.Connection = YourConnection;
        Update.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Update.CommandText = "usp_YoureStoredProcedure";
        Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.Toint16(Session["PatientID"])); //the convert varies on what data type you are using this is just an example
```

Well this is again just examples if you want a more definitive answer try posting or telling us more.

Comment: but when i try to put the Session ["PatientID"] = YoureGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[indexOfPatientID].Text;

Comment: I could not get the .Cells[indexOfPatientID].Text...so what could be the problem can you please let me know?

Comment: -_- ofcourse it would not work you need to insert in the [indexOfPatientID] the index of your patient ID eg [1],[2]

Comment: and it should also be in an event lets say CheckBoxCheckChanged event or sElectedIndexChange event of Gridview.

Comment: i have put the below code in CheckBoxCheckChanged event protected void chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Session["patientid"] = gvDoctorList.SelectRow.Cells[1].Text;           
        } still the error in selectrow. ? what to do now?

Comment: Okay i think i know what is your error, that code would only take effect if you have selected a row in your Gridview you need to select the row first,you can use the AutoGenerateSelect in the Properties to True, Select first a data in gridview then check a checkbox, induce a postback then voila. you have the PatientID in the session.

Comment: error is as below : Error193 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.SelectRow(int)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: it is `.SelectedRow.Cells` not `.SelectRow` you have a very poor eyesight. it is indicated above.

Comment: aahhh....thx....i try but when i put the debug on session line it show error that Object reference not set to an instance of an object....what wrong?

Comment: this code :  Session["patientid"] = gvDoctorList.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;